# How to check if list element in a dictionary is the same as the key in a dictionary and then print the value of the key with the list element

Tags: python, key-value, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

```
recipedict = {'sandwich':['a buttered sandwich',[['bread','13'],['butter','4']]]}
supplydict = {'bread':['150','15','james'],'butter':['15','12','allen'],'sugar':['15','12','marc']}
supplierdict = {"james":'12345234',"allen":'17682342'}
```

for example I have these 3 dictionaries. I need to check if the inner element of the second value of the recipedict is in the supply dict. so check if bread and butter is in the supply dict. If bread and butter is in the supplydict, get the second value of the supplydict, in this case it would be james and allen, and get the first value in supplier dict. then print the associated values with each other

```
ingredient: bread

amount needed: 13

supplier: james

supplier contact: 12345234



ingredient: butter

amount needed: 4

supplier: allen

supplie contact: 17682342
```

i tried getting all the lists together but i only print the whole list with the associated dictionary value

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

for key, value in recipedict.items():
    onevalue = value[1]
    #print(onevalue)
    actuallist = [item[0] for item in onevalue]

    valew = []
    for k in actuallist:
        if k in supplydict:
            
            valuee = supplydict.get(k)
            valew.append(valuee[2])

    print(valew)

    z = flatten(onevalue)
    #print(y)

    n = 1
    word = valew
    for i in range(n, len(onevalue) + n, n + 1):
        onevalue.insert(i, word)

    print(onevalue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
goal = 'sandwich'
for ingredient, needed in recipedict[goal][1]:
    _, _, supplier = supplydict[ingredient]
    contact = supplierdict[supplier]
    print('ingredient', ingredient)
    print('amount needed', needed)
    print('supplier', supplier)
    print('supplier contact', contact)
    print()
```

Comment: hello thank you for replying, is "goal" a placeholder?

Comment: In this case, `goal = "sandwich"`.  Presumably, the recipe dict is going to contain more than one recipe, so you need a variable to specify what food is being prepared.

Comment: thank you its working! my last question is there a way to go throught all the keys in the dictionary instead of just one?